# python query on Postgres

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to get the fields of each row in stored procedure in a Postgres DB.  I keep getting "tuple index out of range"  I am basically copying and pasting the code from a tutorial website and still getting the same error.

When I do only row[0] it print out the entire query.

```
ConfRoom =  ("ConfRoom1",612,1589540397,1589540425,/var/lib/freeswitch/recordings/10.91.50.217/archive/2020/May/15/7b4def4e-0494-439f-8540-1f339e3ec375,1a4652e7-61fc-4fb8-b564-19adec09ec0e)
tuple index out of range

#!/usr/bin/python3
import psycopg2
from config import config

def connect():
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    conn = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        params = config()

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

        # create a cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # execute a statement
        postgreSQL_select_Query = 'SELECT "public"."fn_get_recordings"()'
        cur.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

        conf_query = cur.fetchall() 

                print(conf_query)

        for row in conf_query:
            print("ConfRoom = ", row[0], )
            print("ConfDescription = ", row[1])
            print("StartEpoch  = ", row[2])
            print("EndEpoch  = ", row[3])
            print("Location  = ", row[4])
            print("MeetingID  = ", row[5], "\n")
```

Comment: Try `print("ConfRoom = ", row[0][0], )` . Can you point to the exact line where you are seeing this error?

Comment: What is the return type of `fn_get_recordings()`? I'm guessing it returns a set of rows or a table. So yeah, you probably want to do `select * from fn_get_recordings()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

select * from fn_get_recordings() worked.